# Как выбрать водяное охлаждение для компьютера?

Tags: железо, пк

Как понять подойдет ли длинная водянка в корпус Vinga gryphon, например DEEPCOOL LE720. На офф сайте корпуса пишут, что подходят радиаторы до 360мм, только я не пойму нужно чтоб конкретно радиатор длиной был до 360мм или есть еще тип водянки 360мм?

Comment: Лично моё мнение - лучше хорошей башни с классическими вентиляторами - ничего нет. Всё остальное требует сильно бОльшего обслуживания и ломается чаще.

Comment: Я спрашивал, что лучше ставить?

Comment: О, пассивная агрессия. Не. Это мой конёк. Не забирай мой хлеб. Ты правда считаешь, что я написал камент просто потому что мне делать нечего? Ты не предполагал, что у меня есть некоторый опыт работы с железом и что я видел некоторое количество мамкиных оверлокеров? А ещё можешь читануть умных людей: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709